# How can I disable WPF button highlight when mouse over or when clicked in runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I've this code in C# to create a button as a child of a StackPanel:

`
Button myButton = new Button();
//All button stuff (Background, text...).

myStackPanel.Children.add(myButton);
`

But, as every button, it highlights every time the mouse is over or when I click it. Is there any way to change that in an easy code (I'm still new to C#) can remove that highlight.

I don't know how to do this. I haven't seen anything explaining this and the only codes I could find were in XAML, and I didn't understand them so couldn't translate them to C#.

The problem is all the code I find is about retemplating the XAML code. What I need is to do what I mentioned in C#, as the control is created from scratch in C#.

Comment: You would do this in xaml by re templating the button. Did you search before asking your question? I would think there'll be an SO question covers this already. I would think twice anyhow. That blue fill is feedback tells your user that something will happen if they click.

Comment: You do need to retemplate it. Check out the built-in template here and copy and paste and remove the behavior you don't want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Frustratingly, I was trying to see if I could override those resources used by the default template - `ControlMouseOverColor` and `ControlPressedColor` - but that won't work because they're `StaticResources` since they're used in `Storyboard`'s. FWIW I always just use my own templates for almost every control because there's almost always something I want to change, so this won't be a bad investment to learn how to do.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at a few of the answers for this and didn't see any I liked much.

WPF controls are lookless, meaning they have fixed behaviour but not specific look to them. You can re template a wpf control to pretty much anything you can describe in xaml.  Many wpf controls have quite complicated templates.

Here's one way to template a button as described.

I've put this style in my window's resources. Usually such styles are in resource dictionaries which are merged in app.xaml.

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NoMouseOverButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"   >
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    </Window.Resources> 
    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource NoMouseOverButtonStyle}"
                Content="This is my Button"
                Click="Button_Click"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The button references the style as a resource.
That style sets some defaults so the button has a border you can see but over ride.

The contentpresenter is critical because this is where whatever you make content of your button will appear.

If I set an actual value on a button then that will over ride the style.
Hence

```
        <Button Style="{StaticResource NoMouseOverButtonStyle}"
                Content="This is my Button"
                Click="Button_Click"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                BorderBrush="Red"
                />
```

Gives me a red border on my button.

A lightgray border is rather simpler than a button has by default.

You could reproduce that. Maybe that'd be an interesting learning exercise.

Lookup the button template on msdn.

Google: "wpf button template msdn"

Take a look at that. Brace yourself - it is complicated.

See the button border brush is hard coded in the template?

Change the style above so it does the same.

Clue:

```
  <Setter.Value>
```

Comment: I love that answer, but I think I didn't explain my problem well. What I need is to recreate exactly what you wrote there in C# code, as the controls will be created in runtime. I'll keep that code, as it may be useful in other projects. Also, I seriously need to find out more about templates, binding and styles. I seriously know almos nothing about them. Thanks for answering my question, but with my current understanding I don't know how to "translate" that code into C# runtime. Could you give me some ideas?

Comment: Why would you think you need to translate xaml into c#? Put the template in a resource dictionary, merge in app.xaml. you can reference the style in xaml or c#.

Comment: That's what I'm going to do. I guess I'll find out some stuff about templates and so on so I understand better the code you gave me. Let's see if I can translate it to C#. People write huge codes with re-template, but I never understand them so StackOverflow and other similar sites are useless for me. Thanks for all the help.